# How does redirecting a command output to a file deals with opening and closing that file?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, redirect

If we redirect a command such as `sar -r 1> a_file.txt` how does this works with opening, writing the output of the command and closing the file?

In other words, how does *redirecting a command output* works in the background opening writing and closing the file?  (specially a command such as the above that periodically and continually sends data to output)

I am wondering if there is some cacheing involved and if some *flushing* (writing the contents to the file) occurs at the end

Comment: The file is opened, then the command runs and only when the command ends, the file is closed. But what is your actual problem?

Comment: My actual problem is quite complex but it is basically I am redirecting a command to a file, the file gets created but with 0 bytes. I am guessing perhaps it is because it was not correctly closed so I want to understand the mechanics of redirecting

Comment: that is the normal behavior.

Comment: so, does the "flushing" of data occurs at the end when the command ends?

Comment: no, it writes to the file when output comes. You can test with something like this:  `( sleep 5; echo 1; sleep 5; echo 2; ) > testfile` and in a second terminal `tail -f testfile`

Answer (score 1):

File redirection (`<input`, `>output`, `2>error`) is handled by the parent shell. The executed command (`sar` in your example) sees only the file handle (`0` => `STDIN`, `1` => `STDOUT`, `2` => `STDERR`) and reads/writes via the file handle. The executed program doesn't even know that anything's redirected.

Since the file (`> a_file.txt`) is opened by the parent shell, when the executed program exits, the parent shell simply closes it, which automatically flushes any buffers.

Comment: so there is only one flush at the end?

Comment: One flush is all it takes. See `man fflush`